# Breeding mosquitoes at lower temperature

Tags: entomology, metabolism, growth, temperature, mosquitoes

It is well known fact that, to slow down the growth of drosophila, they are grown at 18-19 degree Celsius. It helps in maintaining stocks for longer time without frequent change of food. Is it applicable to mosquitoes? especially *Aedes aegypti*?  can we slow down its growth by growing them at lower temperature?

Comment: I think there are 2 questions : temp for breeding and, temp for growing larva. I see larva dormant at about 45 F, then at 60+ F they are active.  again.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Possibly even three, as written - temp for maintaining larvae, and temp for maintaining adults. I'd suggest editing out "breeding" from the title, unless you really want to know about this, but I think effects on larvae and adults can be answered as two parts of the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Check "[breeding temperature](https://www.google.fr/search?num=100&ei=MIhxWo_PGoz4kwXjp5-ACQ&q=%22breeding%20temperature%22%20mosquitoes&oq=%22breeding%20temperature%22%20mosquitoes&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.12406.25620.0.25859.45.41.4.0.0.0.170.3738.31j9.41.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.45.3859.6..0j46j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i46k1j0i20i263k1j33i160k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.80.wL5y7DSHlFM)" and similar obscure phrases for the search.

There's a study on physical aspect of mosquitos bred in cold, they perhaps didn't note any significant metabolism change, you can read the articles, they mostly cover wing length scales and follicles.

There's a study on [lave development speed](http://server.ege.fcen.uba.ar/gem/pdf/Loetti%20et%20al.%202008.pdf) which passes over breeding temps, it may however cover "egg temperature".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3992806/ is a NIH paper that gives a quick overview on maintaining an A. aegypti colony.  From the description they are somewhat fussy, but some of the lines imply temperature sensitivity at least at certain stages.

try google 'protocol for maintaining mosquito colony'

Comment: Dear Sherwood, I hope u did not understand my question properly. I know the standard protocol for rearing mosquitoes. My question is whether rearing them will slow down their metabolism and thereby their growth? if so will rearing at lower temperature harm them in any way other than their growth? (like their survival, lifespan, mating behavior,egg laying behavior etc.,)

Comment: Also just wanted to comment that Aedes aegypti is widely accepted to be the *least* fussy mosquito species to care for. We have far more trouble with Culex and Anopheles than any of our Aedes.